# Bind a TextBox to the Sum of a DataTable Column

Tags: vb.net, textbox, datatable, sum, bindingsource

### Context

I would like to have a footer under my grid to show some stats about the datas.

Such as Sum of some columns and average of some other.

### Half solutions I've found

I've found two things intersting to help me do this, binding the databox to a bindingSource, BUT it's only the selected line that is shown into the textBox...

```
myTextBox.DataBindings.add("Text", myGrid.DataSource,"Weight")
```

And getting the Sum of a column in the grid, BUT it doesn't update if I change the grid :S

```
myTextBox.Text = myGrid.DataSource.DataSource.DataSet.Tables(0).Compute("Sum(Weight)","")
```

### Question

Is there a way to have both?

The auto updates as with BindingSource and the Sum as with Compute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a DataTable as the binding source, you can just wire the RowChanged event and compute changes there:

```
Private Sub myTable_RowChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
                              ByVal e As DataRowChangeEventArgs) _
                              Handles myTable.RowChanged
  myTextBox.Text = myTable.Compute("SUM(Weight)", String.Empty)
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah I think it's the simplest way with the dataTable...

The answer may be a little bit late tho, 
Even tho I won't use it this time maybe it'll be usefull later ^^,